# Joining dataframes (columns side by side) inside a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

**EDIT**
I tried to append data to a list but I'm getting a 100x100 dataframe...

I'm generating dataframes inside a nested for loop, it looks like this:

```
for i in range(0,10):
  arr=[]
  appended_data = []

  for j in range(0,100):
      # In the real case I have some real math that depends on the i and j, it looks like:
      r=10*d[j,(i+1)]
      # appending the values of r to an array
      arr.append(r)
      # creating the dataframes with arr
      df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
      appended_data.append(df)
  df2=pd.concat(appended_data, axis=1)
```

So, at the end of the outer loop, I will have 10 dataframes. How to join (not concatenate or merge) these dataframes side by side (column-wise)?

Comment: Use `pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)`

Comment: I tried that and I got `first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"`

Comment: Store the dataframes in a list inside loop and use the above code outside it.

Comment: I've tried that either.  I will edit the code above to reflect it but I'm getting df2 with 100 columns and 100 rows

Comment: there are indentation problems and like this I'm not sure but `appended_data = []` should be before the `for i in ...` loop, `df = pd.D...` and `appended_data.append(df)` should not be in the `for` loop j but at the same level as the loop j (so one indentation less). finally, `df2 = ...` should not be inside the loop i but at the first indentation level (same as the `for i in ..`)?

Comment: Thank you very much!